# How can I terminate a ping output in a linux terminal on a AMI (Amazon Machine Image) machine

Tags: command-line

I am on a Lightsail Instance and I dont want to keep having to close and reopen a terminal. I can not even do `Ctrl + C` inside of the terminal. The only thing that outputs is the letter c. I also tried using the `fg` command that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing Ctrl+Z. It works for me on Amazon Linux 2 AMI. It terminates the ping response and takes you back to the `$` prompt.